# Assign class (fancybox) to SVG element

Tags: css, svg, fancybox

I'm trying to assign a class (video.js) to a SVG element. Somehow the class is disabled. My attempt below doesn't work.

```
<a class="video" xlink:href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1&amp;
autoplay=1" title="The Falltape"><circle cx="168" cy="79" r="59" fill="green" />
</a>
```

It's working fine when I put it with some plain text, without the SVG-circle

```
<a class="video" title="The Falltape" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?
fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />TEXT</a>
```

Linking to video.js

```
Query(document).ready(function() {

$(".video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 853,
        'height'        : 480,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
        'wmode'         : 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `class` attribute into the XLink namespace, put the `href` attribute into the XLink namespace:

```
<a class="video" xlink:href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1&amp;
autoplay=1" title="The Falltape"><circle cx="168" cy="79" r="59" fill="green" />
</a>
```

Make sure that the SVG around this is correct, too.

Comment: I tried suggesting that (and then deleted the answer as it was going nowhere). He's actually got some jquery problem with the class and the fancybox, presumably beacuse in SVG a class attribute is animatable and jquery doesn't understand it is not the same as HTML.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, though Robert suggested that and somehow it doesn't work. It must have something to do with jquery and svg-elements. Is there any way to assign the jquery to the svg-element without using class?

Comment: @Sebastian: If the wrong namespacing in your first code example isn't the issue, maybe correct it so that it doesn't lead to false assumptions.